# Is there any way to replicate Compact form of Pivot Table of excel in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working on a excel report automation using Python. In the excel report, i am using pivot table with the report layout as "Compact Form" --> Where one or more column is shown as a row header. for example - i have below input data

```
Country         City         Employee    Salary $ 
 Mexico         Chiapas      A        100,000 
 Mexico         Chihuahua    B        245,132 
 Mexico         Chihuahua    C        200,000 
 Mexico         Chihuahua    D        175,000 
 United States  Alabama      E        106,088 
 United States  Alaska       F        56,121 
 United States  Arizona      G        9,737 
 United States  Arizona      H        250,000
```

In excel report i am showing it as -

```
Row Labels  Sum of Salary $
Mexico      720,132 
 Chiapas    100,000 
   A        100,000 
 Chihuahua  620,132 
   B        245,132 
   C        200,000 
   D        175,000 
United States   421,946 
 Alabama    106,088 
   E        106,088 
 Alaska     56,121 
   F        56,121 
 Arizona    259,737 
   G        9,737 
   H        250,000
```

Here in the compact view instead of showing country and City in a separate column, i am showing them as a row header which is a functionality in excel.
I am trying to replicate the same view in Python. I have used pandas dataframe to input the raw file. I have used df.pivot and df.pivot_table but unable to get the above view.

I am trying df.pivot and df.pivot_table functions but only getting usual view as below -

```
Country          City      Employee Sum of Salary $
Mexico           Chiapas        A    100,000 
                 Chihuahua      B    245,132 
                                C    200,000 
                                D    175,000 
United States    Alabama        E    106,088 
                 Alaska         F    56,121 
                 Arizona        G    9,737 
                                H    250,000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier with applying multiple `groupby` and `concat` however you want a sorted frame thus my answer is a specifically can solve your problem:

```
df

    Country         City       Employee  Salary
0   Mexico          Chiapas    A         100000
1   Mexico          Chihuahua  B         245132
2   Mexico          Chihuahua  C         200000
3   Mexico          Chihuahua  D         175000
4   United States   Alabama    E         106088
5   United States   Alaska     F         56121
6   United States   Arizona    G         9737
7   United States   Arizona    H         250000
```

The Code:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
country = df.groupby("Country").sum()
for i in range(len(country)):
    c = pd.DataFrame(country.iloc[i])
    c = c.reset_index(drop = True)
    c.index = c.columns
    c = c.reset_index()
    c.columns = ["Row Labels", "Salary"]

    city = df[df["Country"] == country.iloc[i].name].groupby("City").sum()


    for j in range(len(city)):
        c2 = pd.DataFrame(city.iloc[j])
        c2 = c2.reset_index(drop = True)
        c2.index = c2.columns
        c2 = c2.reset_index()
        c2.columns = ["Row Labels", "Salary"]
        employee = df[df["City"] == city.iloc[j].name].groupby("Employee").sum()
        c3 = employee.reset_index()
        c3.columns = ["Row Labels", "Salary"]

        res = pd.concat([res,c,c2,c3])

res = res.reset_index(drop = True)
res = res.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)
```

Result:

```
res


    Row Labels       Salary
0   Mexico           720132
1   Chiapas          100000
2   A                100000
3   Chihuahua        620132
4   B                245132
5   C                200000
6   D                175000
7   United States    421946
8   Alabama          106088
9   E                106088
10  Alaska           56121
11  F                56121
12  Arizona          259737
13  G                9737
14  H                250000
```

If you dont mind the sort of labels the following solution is faster (if you have a large dataset):

```
c1 = df.groupby(["Country"])["Salary"].sum().reset_index()
c1.columns = ["Row Labels", "Salary"]

c2 = df.groupby(["Country","City"])["Salary"].sum().reset_index()[["City","Salary"]]
c2.columns = ["Row Labels", "Salary"]

c3 = df.groupby(["Country","City","Employee"])["Salary"].sum().reset_index()[["Employee","Salary"]]
c3.columns = ["Row Labels", "Salary"]

res = pd.concat([c1,c2,c3])

res


    Row Labels          Salary
0   Mexico              720132
1   United States       421946
0   Chiapas             100000
1   Chihuahua           620132
2   Alabama             106088
3   Alaska              56121
4   Arizona             259737
0   A                   100000
1   B                   245132
2   C                   200000
3   D                   175000
4   E                   106088
5   F                   56121
6   G                   9737
7   H                   250000
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks mate. You saved me. The code is working absolutely fine.